# How to make the title of a table fit the width of the table

Tags: tables, captions, threeparttable

I have the following table with title which is wider than the width of the tabular material. How do I make the title fit the the width of the table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}

\usepackage[width=.75\textwidth]{caption}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{table}
\caption{Quite a long title for the table that tends to be wider than the table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{>{\quad}ll}
% \toprule
%& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\midrule
\rowgroup{Tests} \\
test1 &0.2\\
test2&0.2\\
test3&3.03\\
test3&0.006\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: x]

Comment: The proper solution is to place the `\caption` directive inside rather than outside the `threeparttable` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using the `threeparttable` environment correctly: You should place the `\caption` statement inside rather than outside the `threeparttable` environment. That way, the caption's width will be restricted *automatically* to that of the `tabular` environment.

More generally, the three formal parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the `\caption` directive, the `tabular` environment (also possible: `tabular*` and `tabularx`), and the `tablenotes` environment. By placing the caption and the tablenotes material inside rather than outside the `threeparttable` environment, their widths will be adjusted automatically not to exceed the width of the tabular material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}

\usepackage[width=.75\textwidth]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight} % optional
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} % note that this comes before "\caption"
\caption{Quite a long title that's no longer wider than the subsequent tabular environment}
\begin{tabular}{>{\quad}ll}
\midrule
\rowgroup{Tests} \\
test1 &0.2\\
test2&0.2\\
test3&3.03\\
test3&0.006\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico's suggestion is better than all the suggestion which are posted here, better to use it...

Comment: Indeed, Thank you @Mico

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is just add `minipage` into your tags, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm,
}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
    \caption{Quite a long title for the table that tends to be wider than the table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{>{\quad}ll}
% \toprule
%& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\midrule
\rowgroup{Tests} \\
test1 &0.2\\
test2&0.2\\
test3&3.03\\
test3&0.006\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

May be some experts will gives the auto fit option for this...

Comment: Why use a separate `minipage` environment if it suffices to place the `\caption` after than before `\begin{threeparttable}`?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for correcting me....

Comment: To make your answer more self-contained, it would help if you stated explicitly how you arrived at `80pt` as the width of the `minipage` environment.

Comment: @Mico I just measured the table body width, and entered the approximate value, nothing else intentionally...

Answer (score 0):

You can add backslash `\\` in the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
        a4paper,
        total={170mm,257mm},
        left=20mm,
        top=20mm,
    }

\usepackage[width=.75\textwidth]{caption}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{table}
        \caption{Quite a long title \\ for the table that tends \\ to be wider than
 the table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\quad}ll}
    % \toprule
    %& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \midrule
    \rowgroup{Tests} \\
    test1 &0.2\\
    test2&0.2\\
    test3&3.03\\
    test3&0.006\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: You can control the width of the caption by controlling the backslash location]

Comment: This is not feasible for large documents, and produces less-than-optimal results. Automatic justification would be preferred.